# Build a convex hull from a given mesh in Bullet

Tags: physics, bullet-physics

According to [this tutorial](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/clicking-on-objects/picking-with-a-physics-library/), a convex hull is the most accurate shape one can build from a mesh? I have two questions regarding this:

1. How do I build a convex hull from a given, complex mesh in Bullet?
2. Should this be done offline? How do most people do this? (that is, create a collision shape from a mesh in games)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using `btConvexHullShape`, calling the `addPoint` method. But that's usually not what you want. You should manually make a much much simpler collision mesh in your 3D modeling tool. Collision meshes don't have to be detailed. Use only a few triangles.

A good way to create an accurate representation is to use a compound shape (`btCompoundShape`) made of convex shapes since working with concave shapes directly is cumbersome. Here I explain how to export *.bullet* files from Blender which can then be imported in Bullet using `btBulletWorldImporter` http://xissburg.com/post/export-bullet-from-blender/